# Passing Values to JavaScript Functions in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

  echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td>" . $row["madh"] . "</td>";

  .....

  echo "<td><input type='button' onclick='detail()' value='d'></td>";

  echo "</tr>";

}

function detail(data){}
```

i want to pass $row["madh"] to detail() but I have problem with "" and ''.

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question as it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put Id here

```
echo "<td id="id_madh">" . $row["madh"] . "</td>";
```

when you click on button as in your code

```
echo "<td><input type='button' onclick='detail()' value='d'></td>";
```

you can get value using jquery like this

```
function detail(){
var value_madh = $('#id_madh').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though isn't the best option, you can try to separate that echo line into different parts

```
echo "<td><input type='button' onclick='detail(" . $row["madh"] . ")' value='d'></td>";
```

Comment: If `$row["madh"]` is a string this will cause the call to fail with an error about an unknown variable, a syntax error, or some other error as the string hasn't been properly quoted.

Comment: that's not true, if `$row["madh"]` is a string, things will work just fine. now, if the array value is not set, you will have errors. but you can use null coalesce to default to an empty string if the array index doesn't exist, like so: `($row["madh"] ?? '')`

Comment: @MarkShust, it is true, if `$row["madh"]` for instance was the string `test` their code would be printed as `detail(test)` ... which would make the interperter try to look for a variable named `test` instead of passing the string `test`

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to escape the quotes?

```
echo "<td><input type='button' onclick='detail($row[\"madh\"])' value='d'></td>";
```

note that the function will be immediately involved on page load, you probably want to wrote this within a closure so it's not actually invoked until it's clicked:

```
echo "<td><input type='button' onclick='function(){ detail($row[\"madh\"]) }' value='d'></td>";
```

Answer (score -1):

First put $row["madh"] in a variable;

```
$var = $row["madh"];
```

then

```
  echo "<td><input type='button' onclick='detail(&#39;$var&#39;)' value='d'></td>";
```